# How to get Dataset with specific Value in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, wcf, ado.net, dataset, sqldataadapter

I have a Data-set which has some columns.There is one Column named  Is_Deleted which has a bool value.

I am retrieving a full Dataset using ado.net Code in WCF Service from SQL Server.

Now I want all the rows in the Dataset which has the Is_Deleted Column value = false.
Initially I was getting the desired result where Stored Procedure itself. Where I was selecting Columns where Is_deleted = false.

i want this  Same operation to be done in C#. 
So please tell me how can I proceed.

Comment: SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(m_command);
dAdapter.Fill(dsPwd);
This is the Code

Comment: If you want to send back DataSet as a response in WCF then I will recommend don't do it. It will expose your meta data plus scheme of your data. Instead, use custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the `DataSet`/`DataTable` you can use `Linq-To-DataSet`:

```
var nonDeletedRows = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => !row.Field<bool>("Is_Deleted"));
```

If you need to persist this query you could create a new `DataTable` via `CopyToDataTable`:

```
DataTable tableWithNonDeletedRows = nonDeletedRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

If the `DataSet` is strongly typed you can use the auto-generated column directly.

For example (assuming the table-name is "TableName"):

```
tableWithNonDeletedRows = ds.TableName.Where(r=> !r.Is_Deleted).CopyToDataTable();
```